# How do I get music to resume playing?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-mediaplayer, android-lifecycle

I have music start playing in Activity A. When Activity B opens, Activity A closes, as well as the music from Activity A stops playing. When I return to Activity A, I would like the music to pick up playing from where it left off. How do I do this?

Comment: Are you using the stock media player?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to store (persistently) the position that your media was at in `onPause()` or `onStop()` of activity A, and then in `onResume()` check the value that was stored and call `seekTo()` on your mediaplayer. Something like this:

to get your SharedPreferences objects:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEdit = prefs.edit();
```

To store and recall the position.

```
public void onPause(){
  super.onStop();
  //It might make more sense to do this right before you call startActivity()
  //to launch activityB then here.
  int position = mp.getCurrentPosition();
  prefsEdit.putInt("mediaPosition", position);
  prefsEdit.commit();
}

public void onResume(){
  super.onResume();
  int position = prefs.getInt("mediaPosition", 0);
  mp.seekTo(position);
}
```

*Note if you use this method you'll also need to set the position to 0 when you are exiting ActivityA without going to B. Otherwise when you come back to it the music is not going to start at the beginning.*

Answer (score 0):

In Activity A, override onPause() method to pause the MediaPlayer and override onResume() to resume the MediaPlayer. And make sure that the mediacontroller object doesnt get destroyed when going to Activity B.

Comment: This is not guaranteed to work. If the phone needs the memory it will reclaim the resources used in Activity A. Including the MediaPlayer which will then be unable to resume upon re-starting activity A

Answer (score 0):

See actually real time media players are handled on services but not on the activities if you observe it carefully.. So my suggestion is that try writing media player in service and better use life cycle methods of the media player class and the activity with service